# MVVM ViewModel-Model

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Can I create an instance of the `ViewModel` in the `View` or it's inappropriate? I would need it, because the `Command` of a `MenuFlyoutItem` dynamically changes depending on the content of the `Button` (the `Button` content depends on a `Json` file).

Comment: If you can, you should absolutely do it. `<UserControl.DataContext><ViewModelNamespace:MyViewModel/></UserControl.DataContext>`

Comment: I can and I created one, but I feel it's not pure MVVM now. (The `App` class create an instance of it, and I use it in the `View` class.)

Comment: What makes you think it's not MVVM looking at my example?

Comment: I think the `App` should set the `dataContext` of the view and the view just uses `Binding` and `Command`.

Comment: That's also a proper solution, but both situations do not defy MVVM. In your approach you can still instantiate a ViewModel in your View but solely for DesignTime support, then you could use `<d:DataContext><ViewModelNamespace:MyViewModel/></d:DataContext>`. Your question however is somehow a bit unclear. Could you elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually there are two approaches for `ViewModel` lifetime - singleton and tied to a specific instance of the view. For global `ViewModels` that are tied to a certain `View` for the whole lifetime of the app you will create a singleton instance of the `ViewModel`. Example for this could be the `ViewModel` of the root page of the app. This page will definitely appear only once in the navigation stack so you can safely use just one instance. A problem appears when there is a way for the user to repeat one `View` multiple times in the navigation stack. If you were using just one singleton instance of the `ViewModel`, by navigating to the second instance of the `View` you would essentially lose the the data tied to the previous instance and after navigating back you would see different data. Example would be a shopping app, where you have a product (A) and in the product view you have a list of related items. If the user selected one of them (say product B), then in cas of singleton `ViewModel` the instance would be refreshed to contain data of product B and when going back you would have to manually change the data back to product A. By having multiple instances of one `ViewModel` for each instance of the tied `View` in the navigation stack you can avoid reloading the data, which could be costly in case they are acquired from a remote service, for example. You can always manage all active `ViewModels` in a global array and remove the references to the ones no longer needed, so they can be freed up from memory.